# python:matlab eigs in python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I try to translate a matlab program into python, but I can not find the match of (matlab eigs) in python.
I tried scipy.sparse.linalg, but they are totally different:
matlab:

```html
>> up_Cx

up_Cx =

   1.0e+03 *

    2.1341    2.1341    2.1341
    2.1341    2.1341    2.1341
    2.1341    2.1341    2.1341

>> [A,D]=eigs(up_Cx)

A =

    0.5774   -0.0961   -0.8108
    0.5774   -0.6541    0.4886
    0.5774    0.7502    0.3222


D =

   1.0e+03 *

    6.4023         0         0
         0    0.0000         0
         0         0    0.0000

>>
```

I tried it in python:

```html
>>> H_CX
array([[ 2134.08350667,  2134.08350667,  2134.08350667],
       [ 2134.08350667,  2134.08350667,  2134.08350667],
       [ 2134.08350667,  2134.08350667,  2134.08350667]])
>>> scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs(H_CX)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/arpack.py", line 1238, in eigs
    % (k, n - 1))
ValueError: k=6 must be between 1 and ndim(A)-1=2
```

and k=1:

```html
>>> H_CX
array([[ 2134.08350667,  2134.08350667,  2134.08350667],
       [ 2134.08350667,  2134.08350667,  2134.08350667],
       [ 2134.08350667,  2134.08350667,  2134.08350667]])
>>> scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs(H_CX)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/arpack.py", line 1238, in eigs
    % (k, n - 1))
ValueError: k=6 must be between 1 and ndim(A)-1=2
>>> scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs(H_CX,1)
(array([ 6402.25052002+0.j]), array([[-0.57735027+0.j],
       [-0.57735027+0.j],
       [-0.57735027+0.j]]))
```

The results are totally different, I'm so confused...

Comment: You need [`numpy.linalg.eig`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html), but eigenvectors are not necessarily unique, and their order can also change.

Comment: Or [`scipy.linalg.eig`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html).  `scipy.sparse.linalg.eig` is intended for sparse matrices.

Comment: Maths note: your matrix has all equal elements. This means that it has a nonzero eigenvalue for eigenvector `[1,1,1]`, and zero eigenvalues (twice) in the orthogonal plane. This means that the latter two eigenvectors are most certainly not unique. *And* you need to read the documentation of the functions you want to use, to make sense of their output.